# rails migration change default value of column with new line character

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

```
def change
    change_column :customer, :email_text, :string, :default => 'First Line \n Second Line \n Third Line'
end
```

I'm trying to get this migration such that my default value for this column will work with new lines. When I use this field with simple_form as so:

```
<%= f.input :email_text, :as => :text, :label => 'E-Mail Text', %>
```

The newline characters are showing up as \n's instead of new lines. Anyone have any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Which DB? Which rails version?

Comment: I'm using MySQL (but I'd hope I could do this in a DB-agnostic way), running Rails 3.2.8 / Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another fine example of this ruby "gem":

```
1.9.3p327 :001 > '\n' == "\n"
 => false
```

Try it as:

```
:default => "First Line \n Second Line \n Third Line"
```